# installing pandas from source

Tags: python, pandas, cython, setup.py

I need some help with installing pandas from source. I compile from the source because I am working on a hpc cluster and I have no administrative rights, and I install in my local folder.

I have looked for the official documentation for installation from source, but I think it is missing.

I do

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/my/local/folder build_ext --inplace --force
```

but then when I import it from python 3.3. it says:

```
ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py uild_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Can it be that I am doing something wrong with `Cython`? Ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Note: pandas >= 0.18.0 will no longer support compatibility with Python version 2.6 [GH7718](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7718) or version 3.3 [GH11273](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11273) -- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html

Comment: then, shall I use an older version of pandas?

Comment: Have you tried Miniconda? http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html